# Swift: Accessing AddressBook on iOS 8 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to use the AddressBook framework in my swift app on iOS 8. It works fine on a simulator, but fails when trying to run on a device. I ask for permission and all of that. I've also tried importing the AddressBookUI framework, but Xcode still gives me the same error ('No such module named 'AddressBook')

Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Provide simplest possible [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the particular problem you describe. But there's no trick to using AddressBook with Swift on iOS 8 device. Works fine.

Comment: This is a compile time error. Only when I'm building to a device though. In the simulator, everything works as expected. To reproduce the issue, Just start a new Swift project, `import AddressBook` and try to build to a device

Comment: Precisely what version of Xcode? Also, share a screen snapshot showing us the exact error. There is zero problem using AddressBook framework in an iOS 8 project, so there's something wrong with how you're doing it or with Xcode itself (very unlikely). Restart Xcode or even reboot the Mac, but that's unlikely to resolve it. There's likely something simple going on, but we need more info.

Comment: Xcode 6.1 (most recent build). Also, turns out it's something with my Xcode. Just tried building to my device using my work computer (with the same Xcode version) and everything went fine. Will see if uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was my Xcode installation. Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode and everything worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

try to set your Target -> build settings -> Enable Modules (C and Objective C) -> **YES**

Comment: This build setting is enabled by default